# AWS to Azure Migration of Linux VM Kernel not supported on Azure

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, azure, migration, azure-site-recovery

I am trying to migrate Linux VM running on AWS to Azure but it has Kernel version (4.4.0-1088-AWS) which is not supported with Azure.

I tried to use Azure Site Recovery to replicate the Virtual machine directly to Azure but the mobility service agent is not installing there due to Kernel version not being supported.

Is there any way to migrate those VMs or Is there any way to clone the same VMs to Azure by creating a new instance and moving data and configuration. 
Current OS Version is Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You can create new instance as per requirement Ubuntu version and then copy manually data

Answer (score -1):

You can treat the Linux VM as physical and migrate to Azure using Azure migrate or Azure Site Recovery.

For more details, see a similar discussion on the MSDN forum - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e542831d-a506-495f-8d4b-61e093c5345a/migrate-from-aws-to-azure?forum=hypervrecovmgr

Comment: Sadiqh please read the question carefully anyway the problem is resolved with some extra  efforts